# How to get list all requests in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurlconnection

I want to get all the list of requests (image/video/css) in UIWebView.
I make podclass *NSURLCache*, and it's working, but i get crash.

**Code:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CacheProxy : NSURLCache

@end

#import "CacheProxy.h"

@implementation CacheProxy

- (NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponseForRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request
{
    NSLog(@"url %@", request.URL);

    return [super cachedResponseForRequest:request];
}

@end
```

**Init:**

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        CacheProxy *cache = [[CacheProxy alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:100 * 1024 * 1024
                                      diskCapacity:0
                                          diskPath:nil];
        [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:cache];

    }
```

**Crash:**

```
CFNetwork`__CFURLCache::SetMemoryLimit(long, long):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem via NSURLProtocol (http://www.raywenderlich.com/59982/nsurlprotocol-tutorial - good tutorial)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyURLProtocol : NSURLProtocol

@end


#import "MyURLProtocol.h"

@implementation MyURLProtocol

+ (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    static NSUInteger requestCount = 0;
    NSLog(@"Request #%u: URL = %@", requestCount++, request.URL.absoluteString);
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try optimizing the NSURLCache:

http://twobitlabs.com/2012/01/ios-ipad-iphone-nsurlcache-uiwebview-memory-utilization/